# Re-connection settings in IBM.XMS

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, xms

Do we have functionality in IBM.XMS to `Re-connection Attempt Count`, `Re-connection Attempt Delay`, `Re-connection Attempt Timeout` settings, just like we have in Tibco ?

I am going to use IBM.XMS in a .NET application to send/receive messages to/from IBM MQ. If for some reason IBM MQ goes down, I believe these settings will allow the .NET application to attempt re-connection and thereby avoid any crash in the application.

**UPDATE**

I got some info at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_automatic_client_reconnection.htm. Using this I am using following:

```
oConFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
oConFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, String.Format("{0}({1})", con.Host, con.Port));
oConFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, ((con.ReconnectTimeout.HasValue && con.ReconnectTimeout.Value != 0) ? con.ReconnectTimeout.Value : XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT));
```

But this is not working. The code is breaking the moment I stop the Queue Manager. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Per Shashi's response, how are you stopping the QMgr?  Have you tried stopping the channel (assuming that it's a client) with `STATE(INACTIVE)` instead of stopping the QMgr?

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  Please use a modern version of MQ client and QMgr though.  The functionality and stability are greatly improved, including the ability to use the client reconnect features.  Please see:

[Automatic client reconnection in .NET](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029650_.htm)

Related and important topics include:

- [Connection Options](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029270_.htm) - The different ways of connecting to MQ natively
- [Connection differences](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029460_.htm) - Describes MQ's use of .Net's managed and unmanaged connections and their differences.

The preceding links were from the v7.5 documentation.  If you need the v8.0 documentation (highly recommended to use the v8.0 QMgr and client which are current as of this writing) go [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.helphome.v80.doc/WelcomePagev8r0.htm?lang=en).

IBM has released a full-function, non-expiring product called [WebSphere MQ Advanced for Developers](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/develop_on_websphere_mq_advanced_at_no_charge?lang=en) if you need a QMgr to test with on your personal workstation.

That comes with the client libraries but if all you need is the client libs, just download the stand-alone client.  Go to the [SupportPacs landing page](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs) and look for names like MC[vr].  The naming should be intuitive after that.  [SupportPac MQC8](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC8) is the V8.0 client, [MQC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC8) is the v7.5 client, etc.

If you need the WMQ Explorer download, pick that up as [SupportPac MS0T](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0T).  In that case, I highly recommend also getting [MS0P](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC8) and unzipping it to the Explorer Dropins folder.

Comment: Thanks Rob, the links that you have given are related to IBM MQ Classes for .NET. I am using IBM.XMS (Message Service Client for .NET). How can we accomplish same in IBM.XMS ? I got some info at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/xms_automatic_client_reconnection.htm but it is not working. Is there some working example related to re-connection using IBM.XMS ?

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean?  What is "it" in this case?  The linked page says that the reconnect settings can be made in the program, in the managed objects, in the CCDT, and in the client.ini file, and if multiples of these are set there is a precedence order.  To say it's not working requires knowing what the settings are in each of these places. (I'm from Missouri - you have to *show me* that it is or isn't set in a given location before I believe you, so I always want to see all of them.)

Comment: Rob, I was referring to the code snippet that I added later in my question. It was not working when I was stopping the queue manager from MQ Explorer. I followed suggestion of Shashi, and it is working. But I need it to work otherwise as well (see my comments to Shashi's post). Is there a way ?

Comment: If the QMgr is shut down by an administrator, MQ assumes it was intentional and requires the admin to deliberately specify the -r.  However, if it crashes, the clients are expected to reconnect.  I can only assume that bouncing the service through the Windows dialog is interpreted as a deliberate shutdown and doesn't trigger the behavior.  Have you tried killing the QMgr from the process table? Please see [Stopping a queue manager manually](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q020590_.htm?lang=en).

Comment: I was simply stopping the IBM MQ Service from Administration Tools > Services. So I believe re-connection will be attempted by client application only when QMgr is shut-down by specifying -r option. This is the only way ?

Comment: That and when the QMgr shuts down abnormally or the channel is stopped.  Did you try killing the MQ processes as suggested earlier?

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention how you are stopping your queue manager. Reconnection will not happen if you are stopping queue manager with `endmqm <qm>` command. You will need to stop queue manager using `endmqm -r <qm>`. The `-r` option notifies the client applications to reconnect. If you are using `MQ Explorer`, then select `"Instruct reconnectable clients to reconnect"` option on `Stop Queue Manager` panel while stopping a queue manager.

Comment: I was using MQ Explorer. I will try out your suggestion. Would this be same when there is Network Failure, or for some reason the MQ service is being restarted ?

Comment: Shashi, I tried your suggestion (selected "Instruct reconnectable clients to reconnect") and it worked. But when I restarted the MQ service from Services, the application crashed straightaway.

Comment: What do you mean by crashes?

Comment: Ideally the application should try to reconnect for the reconnect-timeout period and then crash (generates unhandled exception), but there it crashes straightaway, the moment I stop service.

Comment: What is un-handled exception are you getting? do you get MQRC 2009 in the exception? Stopping MQ service will stop queue manager and this is treated as a normal shutdown. Reconnection will occur if queue manager is stopped using -r or abrupt termination.

Comment: After stopping the IBM MQ Service from Administration Tools > Services, the application receives 2162 (MQRC_Q_MGR_STOPPING) followed by 2009 (MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN). So I believe, under network-failure or normal shutdown there will be no re-connection. What is abrupt termination ?

Comment: There will be reconnection if there is a network failure. But no reconnection if queue manager is shutdown normally without -r option.

Comment: Does the reconnection happens for network failure even when using MessageListener to receive messages?                                                              If YES, are there any settings available to bring down the reconnection attempt interval time so I get know about the error much earlier.

Comment: Look at this https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/prx_rtt_client_reconect_timeout.htm